# PHP Can't Decrypt GnuPG Ciphertext

Tags: php, public-key-encryption, gnupg

I'm having difficulties decrypting ciphertext using PHP's GnuPG native libraries. The code I'm using is:

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function encrypt_string($str,$fingerprint) {
    $res = gnupg_init();
    gnupg_addencryptkey($res,$fingerprint);
    $enc = gnupg_encrypt($res, $str);
    return $enc;
}
$enced = encrypt_string("test", "D7D8FB1E8A0C9C51C456E802071FA90142FB8D90");
echo "Encrypted: <br>";
echo $enced."<br>";
$res = gnupg_init();
gnupg_adddecryptkey($res,"D7D8FB1E8A0C9C51C456E802071FA90142FB8D90","");
$plain = gnupg_decrypt($res,$enced); echo "<br>";
echo "Error: ". gnupg_geterror($res);
echo $plain;
```

The encryption works fine, though.
Referring to a comment in PHP's manual, which is [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gnupg-decrypt.php#95911), it says GnuPG ver. > 2 omits plain passwords, however I created the key above without password, but the `gnupg_geterror();` returns the same output: `Error: get_key failed`. Referring to another document [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG#Unattended_passphrase), it instructs to *allow loopback pinentry mode*, however I can't find `gpg-agent.conf`, GPG version I'm using is `gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.20`.

Also, why when echoing the encrypted text, the format is not valid, so that I have to manually add newlines in order to be able to decrypt the ciphertext, in, for example, Kleopatra?

In addition, here are the permission settings of GNUPGHOME env files, in `/home/myuser/.gnupg` (btw, does apache2 uses this env?):

```
drwx------ 2 myuser myuser 4096 Jul 22 12:07 private-keys-v1.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 3897 Jul 22 12:07 pubring.kbx
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 1967 Jul 22 11:23 pubring.kbx~
-rw------- 1 myuser myuser  600 Jul 22 12:04 random_seed
srwxr-xr-x 1 myuser myuser    0 Jul 22 11:23 S.uiserver
-rw------- 1 myuser myuser 1360 Jul 22 12:07 trustdb.gpg
```

Using `gnupg_keyinfo($res, '');`, I can see that the mentioned key is already imported.